# Array list em array multidimensional

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Eu tenho esse laço:

```
aaff = [];contador_selecionados=0;
$(' .values .layout .acf-input').children('').each(function(index,element){
contador_selecionados++;
aaff.push( element.value);
console.log(contador_selecionados);
 }); 
console.log(aaff);
```

Que retorna:

```
Array(9) [ "calças", "XXS", "16", "fita", "M", "13", "calças", "XXS", "1" ]
```

Agora, preciso dividi-lo em 3 tal como:

```
[calças, xxs,16]
[Fita , M,13]
[Calça, xxs,1]
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Consegue disponibilizar o `HTML` da página para informarmos qual seria a melhor abordagem para o seu caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```js
aaff = [ "calças", "XXS", "16", "fita", "M", "13", "calças", "XXS", "1" ];

var ret = [];
for (var i = 0; i < aaff.length; i += 3) {
    ret.push([aaff[i], aaff[i + 1], aaff[i + 2]]);
}

console.log(ret);
```

Ou isso:

```js
aaff = [ "calças1", "XXS", "16", "fita", "M", "13", "calças2", "XXS", "1" ];

var ret = {};
for (var i = 0; i < aaff.length; i += 3) {
    ret[aaff[i]] = {tipo: aaff[i + 1], tamanho: aaff[i + 2]};
}

console.log(ret);
```

Comment: obg victor, tens ideia como posso ter o nome do array com calças {xxs,16}, Fita{m,13} ?

Comment: @I-amSam Não sei se entendi o que você quer, mas se o que você quer é um JSON onde calças e fita sejam chaves e `xxs, 16` e `m, 13` sejam valores, então não vai dar porque haveria duas chaves "calças".

Comment: é isso , esquece que sao dois keys iguais , imagina que é calças1 e calças2

Comment: @I-amSam Editado. Serve para o que você queria?

Comment: Perfeito , Obrigado Victor

Answer (score 1):

Com a função `reduce` do JavaScript você consegue esse resultado.

**Veja o exemplo ao vivo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/ovqn2c6t/**

Pelo que você explicou, seu conjunto de dados é de 3 itens dentro da lista. Ou seja, a cada 3 itens da lista original você monta um novo item na nova lista.

```
// Dados recebidos.
const dados = [ "calças", "XXS", "16", "fita", "M", "13", "calças", "XXS", "1" ];

// Total de itens que compõem um conjunto
const conjunto = 3;

//Nova lista
const dadosMapeados = dados.reduce((val, cur) => { 
   if (val.length === 0 || val[val.length - 1].length === conjunto) val.push([]); 
   val[val.length - 1].push(cur); 
   return val; 
}, []);
```

**O resultado para `dadosMapeados` será este:**

```
[
    ["calças", "XXS", "16"],
    ["fita", "M", "13"],
    ["calças", "XXS", "1"]
]
```

Se precisa usar **JSON** ao invés de **ARRAY**, use a função `map` do JavaScript em cima do resultado. Mas você precisa garantir que o array tenha elementos suficientes ou fazer uma verificação trocando `item[0]` para `item.length > 0 ? item[0] : null` no exemplo abaixo.

```
dadosMapeados = dadosMapeados.map(item => { return { 
    nome: item[0], 
    tipo: item[1], 
    tamanho: item[2]
}});
```

**Agora, o resultado para `dadosMapeados` será este:**

```
{
    {nome: "calças", tipo: "XXS", tamanho: "16"},
    {nome: "fita", tipo: "M", tamanho: "13"},
    {nome: "calças", tipo: "XXS", tamanho: "1"}
}
```